# Customer Community licence is not allowing to give view all access on account

Tags: community, permissions, user, customer-community, owd

Organization-wide default is Public read/write. I want a community user to access all account from community. I tried to give view all access through permission set but getting an error -

> . The user license doesn't allow the permission: Read All Accounts

Currently, I am using `Customer Community` license and `Customer Community User` profile. What is the workaround for this? Or which license should I use for giving view all access to `Account` to a community user?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make OWD of account as Public Read Only??

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Currently it is Public Read/Write and Default External Access is Private.

Comment: Can you make Default Expernal Access as Public R/O , it would be as as good as giving View All at profile level

Comment: Okay. That makes sense to me. Let me try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, we cannot give View All permission on Account for Community License profile, Making OWD as Public Read Only Serves the same purpose.

The only thing to consider is - Any other community you start/have would also get Account Access as Public Read Only.